# Cannot find module 'colorthief'

Tags: node.js, npm, color-thief

I am trying to run colorthief, and I downloaded it from the github repo directly(as npm install -g colorthief or npm istall --save colorthief) did not work. I have colorthief in node_modules, and test.js in colorthief. However, I get the following error message. Any advice?

**test.js**

```
//text logging init @ output.txt
const fs = require('fs');
const myConsole = new console.Console(fs.createWriteStream('./output.txt'));

//init colorthief
const { resolve } = require('path');
const ColorThief = require('colorthief');

//load image
const img = resolve(process.cwd(), 'cropped_image.jpg');

//getting color
ColorThief.getColor(img)
        .then((color) => {
                myConsole.log(color);
        })
```

**error msg**

```
d4@d4-desktop:~/myflection/node_modules/colorthief$ node test.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'colorthief'
Require stack:
- /home/d4/myflection/node_modules/colorthief/test.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/d4/myflection/node_modules/colorthief/test.js:7:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/home/d4/myflection/node_modules/colorthief/test.js' ]
}

Node.js v17.9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but I don't think you want to run anything from within the `node_modules` folder.

Move test.js to `myflection` and run it from there.